# recyclerview.addOnItemTouchListener i need to add multiple products to a cart recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-volley, cart

I'm getting only one product to PlaceOderActivity. i need multiple products to cart
I need multiple products to placeOder

```
recyclerview.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(getApplicationContext(), new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                        ProductsList selItem =  listItems.get(position);
                        final String[] strings = {
                                selItem.getProductName(),
                                selItem.getSalePrice(),
                                String.valueOf(selItem.getQnty()),
                        };
                        Log.w(TAG, Arrays.toString(strings));
                        final String itemname =  listItems.get(position).getProductName();
                       final float price = Float.parseFloat(listItems.get(position).getSalePrice());
                      final int qnty =  listItems.get(position).getQnty();
                      ButtonBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(ProductListActivity.this,PlaceOderActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra("itemname",itemname);
                            intent.putExtra("Price",price);
                            intent.putExtra("qnty",qnty);
                            intent.putExtra("strings",strings);

                            startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        });
                        }
                })
        );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically what you're doing is you're only keeping track of the last product the user added to the cart.

Each time your code reaches your RecyclerItemClickListener you replace the previous item with the new one.

What you need to declare is this (as a class property):

```
private List<Product> productsList = new ArrayList()
```

Each time the user clicks to add a product you just append it to the list like so:

```
productsList.add(Product)
```

And then your can serialize and deserialize the list in your Intent extras or even just save the serialized string to a cache file that you can load up in the next activity.

Here's a better example:

```
public class Product {

   /** Property name */
   String name;

   /** Property salePrice */
   String salePrice;

   /** Property quantity */
   String quantity;

   /**
    * Constructor
    */
   public Product() {
   }

   /**
    * Gets the name
    */
   public String getName() {
      return this.name;
   }

   /**
    * Sets the name
    */
   public void setName(String value) {
      this.name = value;
   }

   /**
    * Gets the salePrice
    */
   public String getSalePrice() {
      return this.salePrice;
   }

   /**
    * Sets the salePrice
    */
   public void setSalePrice(String value) {
      this.salePrice = value;
   }

   /**
    * Gets the quantity
    */
   public String getQuantity() {
      return this.quantity;
   }

   /**
    * Sets the quantity
    */
   public void setQuantity(String value) {
      this.quantity = value;
   }
}
```

Now you need a list of products in your ProductListActivity, and each time a user adds a product to the cart you append to the list using list.add() instead of what you did in your ModelCart by using your setter which replaces the list each time.

Comment: Can you elaborate as to what exactly isn't working? or do you just need a concrete example on how to do it instead of my simplified explanation above?

Comment: nope...i'm just using this line in recycyclerview.addOnItemTouchListener  **ModelCart.setData(productsList);**

Comment: ModelCart.setData(productsList); this is also passing only one value to next activity

Comment: Can you post your implementation of the setData function, or the entirety of the ModelCart class for that matter.

Comment: public class ModelCart{

    private static List<ProductsList> data = new ArrayList<ProductsList>();

    public static List<ProductsList> getData(List<ProductsList> data123) {
        return data;
    }

    public static void setData(List<ProductsList> data) {
        ModelCart.data = data;
    }
}

Comment: Ok, what you're doing with your code is replacing the list everytime the user add a product.

Comment: then how can I do this in a simple WAY!

Comment: **LOGS**

PlaceOder: Chilli Powder 90.0 6
PlaceOder: Chilli Powder 90.0 7
PlaceOder: Chilli Powder 90.0 8
PlaceOder: Turmeric Powder 90.0 6
PlaceOder: Turmeric Powder 90.0 7
PlaceOder: Turmeric Powder 90.0 8

Comment: Ok, can you post the relevant bits of code from your activity here? including your updated Listeners.